# How can I aggregate sub-values into arrays with jq?

Tags: json, shell, jq

I'm new to `jq` and try to extract the values of the `images` keys into a new key, so that

```js
{
  "environments": {
    "staging": {
      "apps": {
        "web": {
          "image": "image1"
        }
      }
    },
    "production": {
      "apps": {
        "web": {
          "image": "image2"
        },
        "admin": {
          "image": "image3"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

becomes something like this:

```js
{
  "environments": {
    "staging": {
      "images": [
        "image1"
      ]
    }
  },
  "production": {
    "images": [
      "image2",
      "image3"
    ]
  }
}
```

I've been fiddling around with `jq` for a while now, could anyone give me a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that in the result you expect the `environments` object to include both `staging` and `production`, you could use this `jq` command:

```
<file jq '.environments |= (.[] |= {images : (.apps|map(.[]))})'
{
  "environments": {
    "staging": {
      "images": [
        "image1"
      ]
    },
    "production": {
      "images": [
        "image2",
        "image3"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This replaces the content of the `environments` object with the a new inner `images` object that contains the list images referred by `apps` and `image`.

The array of images is built using the jq builtin `map()` function.